# $\pi$ is not algebraic of degree one or two

Tags: number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

Can someone help me understand the explanations made in the last two paragrapghs, starting from the sentence "Since the factors $P(x)$ and $P(x)-P(0)...$"

I think I need to be more spesific to get an answer..
First of all, can you show that the expressions $P(x)$ and $P(x)-P(0)$ in $f^{(2k)}(x)$ are nonzero for $x=0$ and $x=\pi$? And they must have a factor of $(2n)!$ in the numerator?

[image]

Comment: Your feeling is correct: there's something missing in this proof. That $F(\pi)+F(0)$ is an integer, does not necessarily lead to a contradiction, if that integer is $0$. But a grown-up proof shows that this is impossible, usually by showing that the integer is not divisible by something, and thus can't be $0$. Unfortunately, I can't give a reference immediately.

Comment: @ProfessorVector The proof shows that $\int_0^\pi f(x) \sin x dx > 0$, so there is still a contradiction when $F(\pi) + F(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Brandon Carter You're right, of course, I've overlooked that statement in the last paragraph.